# From topological actions on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to isometric actions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

It is known that if a finite group $G$ admits a faithful *topological* action on the 3-sphere $S^3$, then $G$ admits a faithful action on $S^3$ by *isometries*. (Pardon proved that a topological action implies a smooth action, and Dinkelbach & Leeb proved that a smooth action implies an isometric one.)  I wonder if this extends to infinite groups acting on $R^3$:

**Question:** Let $G$ be a finitely generated group that admits a faithful, co-compact, topological action on $R^3$, such that no orbit has an accumulation point. Must $G$ admit an action by isometries on one of Thurston’s geometries, preserving the above properties (i.e. faithful, co-compact, accumulation-free)?

**Update:** The comments below suggest that the answer is negative in this generality (an "official" answer with references and explanation would be welcome). **What if G is assumed to be Gromov-hyperbolic?** I'm most interested in the 1-ended case, anticipating an isometric action on $\mathbb{H}^3$. (1-endedness excludes $\mathbb{S}^2 \times \mathbb{R}$.) This is partly motivated by Cannon's conjecture.

By topological action I mean an action by homeomorphisms.

**Update:** instead of just assuming that no orbit has an accumulation point, I'm happy with stronger discreteness conditions such as proper discontinuity

Comment: Could you define "cocompact"? By "the orbit has no accumulation point" do you mean that it has no accumulation in the orbit, or in the ambient space?

Comment: @YCor: By cocompact I mean that there is a compact subset K of R^3 such that the image of K under the action of G covers R^3. The other condition says that the orbit of any point has no accumulation point in R^3.

Comment: The second condition means "proper action"?

Comment: it's certainly wrong as stated even in smooth case. There are closed aspherical 3 manifolds which are glued from several geometric pieces  but are not geometric themselves. E.g. graph manifolds or more generally irreducible manifolds all of whose pieces in the JSJ  decomposition are aspherical. The universal covers are $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch: I don’t see how this yields a counterexample. What is your group, and why can’t it act isometrically on one of Thurston’s geometries?

Comment: @Agelos the group is the fundamental group of the resulting closed aspherical manifold acting on the universal cover  by deck transformations. it can not act isometrically discretely and cocompactly on any of the Thurston geometries because it's neither virtually solvable nor is it Gromov Hyperbolic.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch: I accept this as a negative answer to my question then. Any references would be appreciated. Could the answer be yes if I assumed G to be virtually solvable or Gromov Hyperbolic?

Comment: @Angelos I suspect the answer should be yes to both but that is a guess. Geometric group theorists might know the answer.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch: You can ask Misha. But I do not see a reason for a positive answer in either case. There are lots of hyperbolic and solvable groups inside $\mathrm{Diff}(\Bbb R^3)$. For Abelian groups, the answer is "yes" trivially? $\Bbb Z^4$ cannot act properly and cocompactly on $\Bbb R^3$?

Comment: @markvs Yes, I was perhaps too optimistic. the assumption is that the group acts on $\mathbb R^3$ properly and cocompactly by homeomorphisms (or diffeomorphisms). I feel that should be restrictive even if no assumptions on geometry are made. You are right about $\mathbb Z^4$ but  what about some abelian groups with torsion? is it clear that they cannot happen? or maybe they can? –

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch: You know better than I. Abelian groups with torsion are virtually torsion-free (virtually direct products of cyclic groups). But I think from the question even  the groups like $\Bbb Z\times G$ where $G$ is finite are not clear.

Comment: For finite groups everything if fine, for $\Bbb Z$ it is also fine, but for the direct product - not clear (at least for me).

Comment: Since $\mathbb Z$ can be ruled out $\mathbb Z\times G$ can also because it contains $\mathbb Z$ as a finite index subgroup and it still acts nicely. But I don't know about something like $\mathbb Z^3\times G$ where $G$ is finite.

Comment: I think $\mathbb Z^3\times G$ case when the action is by diffeos can be understood. The $\mathbb Z^3$ action should be free so we can quotient by it first and get an action of $G$ on $T^3$. by averaging this can be made isometric with respect to some smooth metric on $T^3$. then Ricci flow (possibly with surgeries) should turn this into a flat $T^3$ and since the Ricci flow preserves isometries the $G$ action will remain isometric in the limit.

Comment: @VitaliKapovitch: you’re right that graph manifolds provide counterexamples, but it’s not true that the fundamental group of a geometric 3-manifold is either virtually solvable or Gromov hyperbolic. The fundamental groups of Seifert fibres manifolds with hyperbolic base are neither of these.

Comment: @HJRW oh right, sorry, I thought I had them all covered and forgot this one. still, graph manifolds are counterexamples to that possibility also.

Comment: I've updated the question: what if G is Gromov-hyperbolic (and 1-ended)?

Comment: The *isometry* part of the question is a red herring: the counterexamples mentioned don't fail because they're topologically "wild", they just fail because there are non-geometric 3-manifolds. A better question might be: "Is every properly discontinuous topological action on a 3-manifold a limit of smooth actions?" It might be worth asking this question separately. Pardon is sometimes active on MO, and probably knows the status of the question.

Comment: In the present form, assuming tameness of the action, the answer is positive. It is an easy corollary of the Geometrization Theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe (though have not checked carefully) that the argument in my paper proves:

> If $\Gamma$ (discrete) acts continuously and properly discontinuously on a smooth three-manifold $M$, then that action can be uniformly approximated by a smooth action.

The point is simply that each step in the argument is local on the quotient space $M/\Gamma$ (which is a reasonable topological space given proper discontinuity).

Here is a (sketched) better argument, which proves the indented statement above as a consequence of my paper.  Fix $x\in M$, and consider the stabilizer $\Gamma_x\leq\Gamma$, which is finite.  Choose coset representatives $g_i\in\Gamma/\Gamma_x$, so $\Gamma x=\{g_ix\}_i$.  Fix a $\Gamma_x$-invariant open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ whose translates $g_iU$ are all disjoint (should exist by proper discontinuity).  Now smooth the action of $\Gamma_x$ on $U$ using my paper, and smooth the homeomorphisms $g_i:U\to g_iU$ using Bing--Moise.  This determines a smoothing of the action of $\Gamma$ on $\Gamma U\subseteq M$.  By making the approximations sufficiently $C^0$-close, we ensure that this smoothed action of $\Gamma$ on $\Gamma U\subseteq M$ splices together with the original action of $\Gamma$ on $M\setminus\Gamma U$ to define a new action of $\Gamma$ on $M$, which is now smooth over $\Gamma U$.  Now iterate a (locally) finite number of times to cover all of $M$.

Comment: @HJRW : does this combine with your answer to give an action by isometries?

Answer (score 3):

My earlier attempt at an answer was a bit of a mess -- let me have another go.

The hypotheses of the question introduce several technical difficulties, but I'm unsure which are crucial and which can be relaxed. Certainly, if we're willing to relax them slightly then we can get a positive answer, so I'll give an answer under certain hypotheses that seem reasonable to me.

The usual discreteness hypothesis in this context is not an absence of accumulation points, but *proper discontinuity*, and it seems to me that this is the natural way to generalise Pardon's theorem.  With the hypothesis of absence of accumulation points (which @YCor rightly points out is strictly weaker) it's not clear to me what happens even for smooth actions. Apologies if this strictly weaker properness hypothesis is the point of the question (but I don't see a connection with Cannon's conjecture).

So let's suppose that $\Gamma$ is a hyperbolic group acting properly discontinuously and cocompactly by homeomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^3$. To keep things simple, let's also assume that $\Gamma$ has a (wlog normal) torsion-free subgroup $\Gamma_0$ of finite index.

Since the action is properly discontinuous and $\Gamma_0$ is torsion-free, the action of $\Gamma_0$ is free and so the quotient $M_0=\Gamma_0\backslash\mathbb{R}^3$ is a closed topological 3-manifold.

By Moise's theorem $M_0$ has a smooth structure, and now $M_0$ is an aspherical 3-manifold whose fundamental group has no $\mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroups, so $M_0$ admits a hyperbolic metric by the geometrisation theorem. This metric pulls back to realise the action of $\Gamma_0$ as an action by isometries on $\mathbb{H}^3$.

Pardon's theorem shows that the action of the finite deck group $\Gamma\backslash\Gamma_0$ on $M_0$ can be approximated by smooth actions, and a theorem of Gabai implies that this action is isotopic to an action by isometries. As a result, the action of the whole group $\Gamma$ on $\mathbb{H}^3$ is also by isometries, as desired.

Comment: Minor point: the OP doesn't assume properness, but a weaker discreteness assumption, satisfied, for instance, by the action of $\mathbf{Z}$ by powers of $(x,y)\mapsto (2x,y/2)$ on $\mathbf{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$.

Comment: Are you saying that the Cannon conjecture is unknown even in the special case of a 3-manifold group?

Comment: @YCor wait: no, I’m not saying that! Sorry, I think I was forgetting that Bestvina—Mess predates geometrisation. I’ll edit later this evening.

Comment: I think Tukia's 1986 "quasiconformal" paper ([DOI link](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02786618)) directly implies that every discrete group quasi-isometric to $X=H^n(\mathbf{R})$ (for $n\ge 3$) has a geometric action on $X$, without passing to any finite index subgroup. (This is also true for $n=2$ but was proved later by other authors.)

Comment: @YCor: Good point! That’s another nice way to conclude. Though I think you need the virtually torsion-free assumption to get to produce the copy of H^3 in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I referred to the last paragraph while the virtual torsion-free assumption was used beforehand. It's intriguing how this assumption could be removed.

Comment: @YCor: Well, I think the other idea for a proof conditional on the Cannon conjecture might work in that case, although there are a few things to check, as I explained in the first version of this answer. These two approaches are not as disconnected as they might at first seem -- there are (still pretty speculative) approaches to the Cannon conjecture conditional on the hypothesis that every hyperbolic group is residually finite.

Comment: My idea was whether there is an "orbifold" version of the Thurston-Perelman hyperbolization theorem. Actually one could try to (inconditionally) solve the same question beforehand for an action on the plane instead of the 3-space.

Comment: @YCor: I think that's a reasonable hope (and certainly some versions are known), but one needs a smooth action.

Comment: I don't mind assuming the action to be properly discontinuous (I'll update the question). This answer is already looking appealing, thanks HJRW! It would be nice to see an aswer dropping the virtual torsion-freeness assumption.

Comment: @Ycor: could you clarify which "same question" you want to have solved for an action on the plane instead of 3-space?

Comment: @Agelos Say, this one: for $n=2$, is every discrete group acting properly cocompactly continuously on $\mathbf{R}^n$ virtually torsion-free? What if assumed in addition to be hyperbolic?

Comment: @YCor: For n=2 this is true, using the classification of compact, 2-dimensional orbifolds and the fact that all orbifold groups are "good in the sense of Serre". (This latter implies that finite extensions of orbifold groups are residually finite, hence also virtually torsion free.) For n=3 and a smooth action it's probably also true by a suitable orbifold version of geometrisation and the fact that 3-manifold groups are also good. The case of a non-smooth action seems interesting, and one should probably ask Pardon. For $n\geq 4$ I suspect it's false, even in the smooth case.

Comment: Actually, I guess I left out an important detail in dimension 2, namely that the action should be smoothable. I suspect this is true and classical (some suitable extension of the Jordan curve theorem) but I don't know a reference.

Comment: For n=2, it is indeed true that every discrete group acting cocompactly and properly discontinuously on R^n is virtually torsion-free. Here is another way to prove it. It is known that every such group G is isomorphic to a Kleinian function group (see e.g. https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2020-373-07/S0002-9947-2020-08026-X/home.html), in particular, G is a group of matrices over C, and we can apply Selberg's Lemma. Hyperbolicity is not needed.

Comment: ... But the fact that G is isomorphic to a Kleinian group used above is the 2D version of my original question. To obtain a proof more likely to extend to 3D, we could instead use the fact that G has an 1-ended planar (hyperbolic) Cayley graph (which the aforementioned paper proves without using that G is Kleinian), and try to deduce that G is virtually-torsion-free from that. Can you do this?

Comment: @Agelos: If your proof produces an *equivariant* embedding of the Cayley graph into the plane then the action on the plane can easily be made piecewise linear, so all the difficulties arising from only assuming the action to be by homeomorphisms go away. The quotient is then visibly an orbifold, and the result follows from the fact that orbifolds admit geometric structures. Virtual torsion-freeness is then a byproduct (and one would still probably use Selberg's lemma to handle the case of triangle orbifolds).

Comment: @HJRW: indeed, my proof produces an equivariant embedding. Moving up to 3D, if G acts on R^3 so that the quotient is homeomorphic to a 3-orbifold, is virtual torsion-freeness still a "byproduct"?

Comment: @Agelos: That's right. Since $G$ is one-ended with no $\mathbb{Z}^2$ subgroups, the orbifold and geometrisation theorems imply that the orbifold is hyperbolic, so $G$ is a finite extension of a Kleinian group. One consequence of Agol's Virtual Haken theorem is that Kleinian groups are also "good in the sense of Serre", from which it follows that $G$ is residually finite and hence virtually torsion-free.

Comment: (I guess I'm assuming that all topological 3-dimensional orbifolds can be smoothed. I think this is probably true. Again, if your action is really piecewise linear this isn't going to be a problem.)